# Can I create a report that will list all previously run reports?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm using Dynamics CRM 2015 and want to create a report that will show all reports run in the last 12 months.

I've been using the Report Wizard and can't seem to find the entity that is created when a report is run. I can find when a report was created but not every time it has been run.

Example of expected results:

Report X

```
4/3/2019   Admin 1

4/2/2019   Admin 3
```

Report Y

```
4/3/2019   Admin 2

4/2/2019   Admin 1
```

I'm not worried about the formats, I will most likely tinker with it after. I simply want to find a way to display every instance any report has been run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on CRM 2015, it would follow that your system is on-prem.

That means you're not able to use the relatively new [Activity Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/enable-use-comprehensive-auditing#what-events-are-audited) a.k.a. Read Auditing that's available in D365 Online, which seems to have [what you're looking for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/enable-use-comprehensive-auditing#user-and-support-related-events).

The out-of-box audit in CRM 2015 would give you some kind of "user access" auditing (i.e. when people login), but not show you specific report runs. It's really designed to capture changes to the data for audited entities.

As far as I know there is no entity record created when a user runs a report. Provided you were willing to hook into and/or replace all the report triggers throughout the system (i.e. in all ribbons), you could hypothetically build something to track report runs. But it seems like that would be cost prohibitive.

According to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2008/11/19/auditing-report-execution-using-the-reportserver-database/) you should be able to pull this info out of the ReportServer DB. I'd quote the relevant parts here but it seems very involved - creating temp tables, etc.